# how to store the value of a checkbox to a table

Tags: php, mysql, html

i want to store the value of a checkbox into my sql database, basically i want to save the default value if it is checked or not.. i am not sure what this would save either true or false?

```
<div><input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="chk"/> Yes! I will come!</div>
```

should I insert into my table like this?

```
'$_POST[chk]'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_POST[chk]` will return the text `Yes`, in your case, if checked, and won't set it at all if not. Knowing this, you can set the db field how you want, say `1` or `0` for tinyint type:

```
$chk = isset($_POST['chk']) ? 1 : 0;
$sql = "update tbl set chk1 = $chk";
```

Comment: Wrong - checkbox will result in sending value if checked, or not sending value if not checked. Your code could work however.

Comment: @Tadeck Yeah, thx for the correction. My answer was all whack. It should be legit now.

Comment: And Shredder has edited his answer......, It will work but not the most elegant solution.

Comment: Should be simply '$chk=1;' on the SECOND line of your code, becuase isset($_POST['chk']) will only return true if checkbox is selected

Comment: @djaqeel Ah, word up! ;) Makes sense hehe

Comment: +1 Your answer is the only one that is reasonable and secure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  And sanitize input before you insert.

Use

```
if(isset($_POST[chk]) ) {  
      $chk = (string) $_POST[chk];
   }
```

Comment: You said _sanitize_? Where do you sanitize it? Your part of code is very insecure (to be more unsecure, you would need to pass it to `eval()`).

Comment: What is the need for sanitizing a checkbox post? Is it because the data can be hacked/altered?

Comment: @Tadeck I did not sanitize it. And how is it **very insecure**?

Comment: @Shredder: You do not need to be a hacker to be able to change what is sent within the value of any checkbox. As a developer you **must** sanitize any input sent from the user (by `GET`, `POST` or in any other way).

Comment: @Tadeck Gotchya. Well, I think my code is protected from that.

Comment: @Shredder: Your code is, this guy's is not. I am surprised answer other than yours have positive voting results.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You should do it like this

```
if(isset($_POST['chk'])):
$chk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['chk']);
else:
$chk = 0;
endif;
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$chk')";
```

Then insert the field as '$chk'.
This is the safest method and it's best to remove the [' '] part of a variable as it may affect your SYNTAX when adding it to the table.

Comment: So you're either inserting 'Yes' or '0'? What if the data gets altered somehow. Seems like that would break the system.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using tinyint(1) datatype for the column in which you plan on storing whether a checkbox has been selected or not.

```
ALTER table `my_table` ADD COLUMN `my_checkbox_col` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 0;
```

Comment: If you have finished with 'planning' the DB for OP, will you please move forward and throw some light on the actual problem of OP?

Comment: Wow, was just a recommendation, as the actual solution was already posted.