# use of checkbox in php to store the value

Tags: php, html

I want to store the values based on the check-box selected sequentially.but i have an error as undefined index : productadd and so on.

Designing part:

```
<table  width="600" style=" border-color:#799647; border-bottom-color:#799647; border-left-color:#799647; border-right-color:#799647; border-top-color:#799647;" border="2" >
    <tr style="border-color:#799647; background-color:#CAF9C5;">

        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><h4  style="color:Green;">Page Name</h4></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><h4  style="color:Green;">Add</h4></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><h4  style="color:Green;">Edit</h4></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><h4  style="color:Green;">View</h4></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><h4  style="color:Green;">Delete</h4></td>

        </tr>
        <tr style="border-color:#799647; background-color:#F5F2BF;">
        <td align="center"><label>Products</label><input type="checkbox" name="screen[]" value="Products Master" align="absmiddle" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="Productsadd" name="Productsadd" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="Productsedit" name="Productsedit" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="Productsview" name="Productsview" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="Productsdelete" name="Productsdelete" value="Yes" /></td> </tr>

        <tr style="border-color:#799647; background-color:#F5F2BF;">
        <td><label>SerialNO</label><input type="checkbox" name="screen[]" value="SerialNO" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="SerialNOadd" name="SerialNOadd" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="SerialNOedit" name="SerialNOedit" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="SerialNOview" name="SerialNOview" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" id="SerialNOdelete" name="SerialNOdelete" value="Yes" /></td> </tr>

        <tr style="border-color:#799647; background-color:#F5F2BF;">
        <td><label>Vechile Make</label><input type="checkbox" name="screen[]" value="Vechile Make" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Vechileadd" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Vechileedit" value="Yes" /></td>
         <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Vechileview" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Vechiledelete" value="Yes" /></td> </tr>

        <tr style="border-color:#799647; background-color:#F5F2BF;">
        <td><label>Retailer</label><input type="checkbox" name="screen[]" value="Retailer" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Retaileradd" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Retaileredit" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Retailerview" value="Yes" /></td>
        <td style="border-color:#799647;"><input type="checkbox" name="Retailerdelete" value="Yes" /></td> </tr>
 </table>
```

when i used to click the save button following codes are going to be executed .but i have a error in the switch case function .
Php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    $post['userid'] =($_POST['userid']);

    if(!empty($_POST['userid']))
     {  
    // if(is_array($_POST['Products'])) 
    // {
        foreach($_POST['screen'] as $post['Pagename'])
        {
        //  myfun($post['Pagename']);
switch($post['Pagename'])
    {
        case "Products Master": 
                                $post['addition'] =($_POST['Productsadd']);
                                $post['edit'] =($_POST['Productsedit']);
                                $post['vieww'] =($_POST['Productsview']);
                                $post['del'] =($_POST['Productsdelete']);
                                break;  

        case "SerialNO": 
                                $post['addition'] =($_POST['SerialNOadd']);
                                $post['edit'] =($_POST['SerialNOedit']);
                                $post['vieww'] =($_POST['SerialNOview']);
                                $post['del'] =($_POST['SerialNOdelete']);
                                break;  
        case "Vechile Make": 
                                $post['addition'] =($_POST['Vechileadd']);
                                $post['edit'] =($_POST['Vechileedit']);
                                $post['vieww'] =($_POST['Vechileview']);
                                $post['del'] =($_POST['Vechiledelete']);
                                break;  
        case "Retailer": 
                                $post['addition'] =($_POST['RetailerOadd']);
                                $post['edit'] =($_POST['Retaileredit']);
                                $post['vieww'] =($_POST['Retailerview']);
                                $post['del'] =($_POST['Retailerdelete']);
                                break;  

        default : 
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("Nothing selected.!!");document.location='userrights.php';
                            </script>
                                <?  

}
                    //echo $post['Pagename'];
        $news->addNews($post);
    //   }  
     }

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Created Sucessfully..!!");document.location='userrights.php';
            </script>
            <?
}
}
  ![this is my visual screen][1]
```

Comment: this has been dealt with so many times on SO. check all the related issues on the right side. Search first, if you can't find anything related to your problem then you can ask a question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store the value of a checkbox to a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084018/how-to-store-the-value-of-a-checkbox-to-a-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it, by checking if the index is set before accessing it.

However, I suggest you look into using arrays instead for your checkboxes to group them into collections for easier parsing:

```
if(isset($_POST['Save']))
{
    $post['userid'] = isset($_POST['userid']) ? $_POST['userid'] : null;

    if(!empty($_POST['userid']))
     {  
    // if(is_array($_POST['Products'])) 
    // {
        foreach($_POST['screen'] as $post['Pagename'])
        {
        //  myfun($post['Pagename']);
switch($post['Pagename'])
    {
        case "Products Master": 
                                $post['addition'] = isset($_POST['Productsadd']) ? $_POST['Productsadd'] : null;
                                $post['edit'] = isset($_POST['Productsedit']) ? $_POST['Productsedit'] : null;
                                $post['vieww'] = isset($_POST['Productsview']) ? $_POST['Productsview'] : null;
                                $post['del'] = isset($_POST['Productsdelete']) ? $_POST['Productsdelete'] : null;
                                break;  

        case "SerialNO": 
                                $post['addition'] = isset($_POST['SerialNOadd']) ? $_POST['SerialNOadd'] : null;
                                $post['edit'] = isset($_POST['SerialNOedit']) ? $_POST['SerialNOedit'] : null;
                                $post['vieww'] = isset($_POST['SerialNOview']) ? $_POST['SerialNOview'] : null;
                                $post['del'] = isset($_POST['SerialNOdelete']) ? $_POST['SerialNOdelete'] : null;
                                break;  
        case "Vechile Make": 
                                $post['addition'] = isset($_POST['Vechileadd']) ? $_POST['Vechileadd'] : null;
                                $post['edit'] = isset($_POST['Vechileedit']) ? $_POST['Vechileedit'] : null;
                                $post['vieww'] = isset($_POST['Vechileview']) ? $_POST['Vechileview'] : null;
                                $post['del'] = isset($_POST['Vechiledelete']) ? $_POST['Vechiledelete'] : null;
                                break;  
        case "Retailer": 
                                $post['addition'] = isset($_POST['RetailerOadd']) ? $_POST['RetailerOadd'] : null;
                                $post['edit'] = isset($_POST['Retaileredit']) ? $_POST['Retaileredit'] : null;
                                $post['vieww'] = isset($_POST['Retailerview']) ? $_POST['Retailerview'] : null;
                                $post['del'] = isset($_POST['Retailerdelete']) ? $_POST['Retailerdelete'] : null;
                                break;  

        default : 
                            ?>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            alert("Nothing selected.!!");document.location='userrights.php';
                            </script>
                                <?  

}
                    //echo $post['Pagename'];
        $news->addNews($post);
    //   }  
     }

        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Created Sucessfully..!!");document.location='userrights.php';
            </script>
            <?
}
}
  ![this is my visual screen][1]
```